# JavaScript click() breaks Bootstrap button's on-click animation

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for styling. I have a button on my page that I want users to be able to trigger with a keystroke.

I've added the following Javascript and it works.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
    if (key === 'j' || key === 'KeyJ' || key === 74) {
      document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});
</script>
```

The HTML for this is just

```
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Button</button>
```

and it looks just like any button styled by [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/).

**PROBLEM**. Normally when you press the button there's a little animation that plays on-click courtesy of Bootstrap. When the click is triggered by the JavaScript though (i.e., the user used the keystroke), that animation doesn't happen, and the user doesn't get any feedback on the fact that the button has been clicked. Since the user will predominantly be triggering the click through the keystroke, I really want that click feedback to be visible.

What is wrong with my code that is breaking the Bootstrap animation? Is there another approach that would let me trigger button clicks with keystrokes like I have here, but doesn't break the on-click feedback animation?

**CODEPEN**: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/byebxg
In the Codepen demo you can try to hover and click on the button and see the little Bootstrap animation play (it doesn't do anything in the demo). You can also "click" on it by pressing "j" because of the JavaScript snippet (I added an alert to show that the keystroke listening is working). However, when the button is "clicked" this way, the button animation doesn't show. Is there a way to make it play even when the click is triggered by the JS script?

Comment: Could you make a codepen or codesandbox demo to replicate the issue so I can help you faster?

Comment: @bntzio Thanks so much for taking a look! I've just added a Codepen demo to the question.

Comment: The key to this is...the styling is being handled in css, not javascript. So the key is to add / remove the "focus" class, which is what bootstrap does when you normally click on the button. (as @Vipul Bhardwaj shows)

Comment: Just answered your question @tangleduniform8 feel free to ask me anything further

Comment: @RichS @ bntzio Great, I've tried your and @ Vipul Bhardwaj's answer and it's working for me now. Many thanks for explaining why it works this way as well so I understand what's going on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap uses JavaScript to handle things like animations in some of their components such as the hamburger menu toggling, but in some of their components like in this case, the buttons, Bootstrap uses CSS to animate the component using simple CSS animations, that is handled using CSS keyframes and transforms and so on.

So in your case, since you're dispatching a click event indirectly, those events are called synthetic events, as opposed to the events fired by the browser itself.

In that way, you have more control on what to do in reaction to those click events, so in your case, you need to add the Bootstrap `focus` class to give the button component the little outline animation.

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.defaultPrevented) {
    return;
  }
  let key = event.key || event.keyCode;
  let hotkeys = ['j', 'KeyJ', 74];

  if (hotkeys.includes(key)) {
    let elm = document.getElementById("myButton");
    elm.classList.toggle('focus');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Button</button>
```

Using the `toggle` method you can then, add the class `focus` when it isn't there and remove it when it is there, after clicking the button directly in the browser or via your keyboard.

You can search for the word `focus` in the [Bootstrap CSS](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css) source code to see what it really does when you append the class to the button component.

Answer (score 2):

So, after looking into this, I am assuming that the animation you are talking about is the increase in the border, right ?

If that is the case, then you can custom build that effect by applying the 'focus' class to the element.

```
.... 
 var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
    if (key === 'j' || key === 'KeyJ' || key === 74) {
      var b = document.getElementById("myButton");
      b.classList.add('focus');
      b.click();
    }
....
```

Note:- Do make sure to remove the focus class on keydown may be to give that animation sort of feel.
Which can be achieved by 
`b.classList.remove('focus')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
    if (key === 'j' || key === 'KeyJ' || key === 74) {
      document.getElementById("myButton").style.background = 'lightgreen';
      document.getElementById("myButton").click();
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }
    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;
    if (key === 'j' || key === 'KeyJ' || key === 74) {
      document.getElementById("myButton").style.background = 'green';
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Button</button>
```

On keyup your button color is changing and your click is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Loader use for show processing -

```
   <button  class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit"  id="load" data-loading-text=" 
   <i class='fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin'></i> Processing Order">Button</button>
```

JavaScript Code is -

```
  <script>
      $('.btn').on('click', function() {
         var $this = $(this);
           $this.button('loading');
              setTimeout(function() {
                     $this.button('reset');
                         }, 8000);
               });
   </script>
```